# Get column names including index name from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that we have a data frame with an index that might have a name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,6,1], 'c':[2,6,0]})
df = df.set_index(['a'])

   b  c
a      
1  3  2
2  6  6
```

What is the best way to get the column names that will include the index name if it is present.

Calling `df.columns.tolist()` do not include the index name and return `['b', 'c']` in this case, and I would like to obtain `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For universal solution need filter `None` if not exist `index.name`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,6,1], 'c':[2,6,0]})

print ([df.index.name] + df.columns.tolist())
[None, 'a', 'b', 'c']

c = list(filter(None, [df.index.name] + df.columns.tolist()))
print (c)
['a', 'b', 'c']

df = df.set_index(['a'])

c = list(filter(None, [df.index.name] + df.columns.tolist()))
print (c)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Another solution with [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) and [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
c = np.insert(df.columns, 0, df.index.name).difference([None]).tolist()
print (c)

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 4):

The index can be temporarily reset for the call:

```
df.reset_index().columns.tolist()
```

If an empty index name is not to appear in the list, do the `reset_index()` conditionally:

```
(df.reset_index() if df.index.name else df).columns.tolist()
```

Comment: @jezrael, @jpp I added a conditional check to the answer. The simple code does function if the index has no name, it just adds an empty string or `'index'` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list` with `filter` after elevating your index via `reset_index`:

```
res = list(filter(None, df.reset_index()))

print(res)

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think with more recent versions of pandas this answer might be more concise:

```
names = list(filter(None, df.index.names + df.columns.values.tolist()))
```

This works for no index, single column Index, or MultiIndex. It avoids calling reset_index() which has an unnecessary performance hit for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have got it from group by operation, I think if that's the case, you need to add reset_index() at the end to get the column names by usual methods.

Answer (score 0):

to get the name of index, try this
df.columns.name

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35192787)